# Stop at first match using regex

Tags: regex

This is an oft repeated question, but somehow I didn't find the previous answers exactly matching my requirement. There is a string

> My name is Pavan. Am I a good boy?

I want to match only the first occurrence of the character `a`(irrespective of whether its at a word boundary or not ) in the above string. The simplest regex

```
a
```

will match all four `a`s present in the string. All the other posts I searched on SO are suggesting using non-greedy match `?`. But `a+?` doesn't solve the problem here as even the non-greedy match would be repeated 4 times.

So how shall I tell the regex engine to stop soon after the first match?

I might have asked a very trivial question, but bear with me as I've just started with regexes.

**PS:** I am using the following 2 engines to verify my results

[GSkinner](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/)

[RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/)

I am not using any specific language and am just using the above tools to perform matches

Comment: What is your language where you'll apply this. E.g., Perl has a modifier exacly for this (bail out after first match and never match again).

Comment: here you go: [matches first a](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?31i4q). So this was just a technical question on how to use gskinner?

Comment: @rubberboots nice :). No, this was a question to know how regex engines iterate over successive matches. I got the point that `global` switch is the one making the regex engine to go ahead inspite of the first match. Thanks mate!

Comment: Pavan, **regular expressions** are one of the last relevant resorts where one can apply some kind of wizardry in information technology (another one is C++11). So it is imo very useful if you try to get in touch with them. But be warned, you'll need at least a year of everyday practice to master them (or was it ten years, I forgot). **[This one](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do)** is your ultimative text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing quantifiers in the regex language with the tools your language/framework gives you. Usually there is a method that returns all matches and one that returns only the first match (and one that just checks whether a regex matches).

In .NET `Regex.Matches` finds all matches, `Regex.Match` finds just the first one and you can use `Regex.IsMatch` to figure out whether a regex matches.

In Java you can use `Matcher.find` to find the first match or iterate to find all.

In Python there is `re.search` and `re.findall`.

Comment: I agree that we can find implementations which return only the first match. But do they too, internally, find all matches and then return only the first?

Comment: No, internally they probably work like Java's public API. There's a function that finds the first match from a given point and finding all matches just uses this method iteratively to find all matches in the string.

Comment: @PavanManjunath: of course they don't, if they are implemented half-decent.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case:

```
^[^a]*(a)
```

But most regex implementations have a function that returns only the first match.

Comment: That works for how I understood your question. On the bottom you can see that it got the first a (via the grouping parenthesis), and it matched: From the start of the string, anything that is not an a, until it found an a. In that case, it matched "I a" which contains the start of the string, I and " " which are not a and the first a, which is contained in the groups on the panel below.

Comment: @Trickfire. I want only the `a` and not everything that precedes it.

Comment: Yea, that's what the parenthesis do, they group it so that the a can be extracted, if you're not using an engine like that, there is usually something you can call afterwords that will allow you to extract the groups. If you're doing it for something like replacing a with something, the only way I know how to do that is to use backreferences.

Comment: Pavan, if you would tell us what language you use that'd all be easier. E.g. in .NET you can have arbitrary-length lookbehind with which you can assert that you want the first `a` that's not preceded by any `a`: `(?<=^[^a]*)a`. But that doesn't work in the majority of languages. You can still use nightcracker's approach if you use the first *capturing group* instead of the whole match.

Comment: From his comment on his original post, it looks like he just wanted the functionality of getting the first match. I was a bit confused on what he was going for.

Comment: @Joey. Thanks for shedding more light on this. As I am new to regexes, I am just using the online tools for matching purposes and not specific languages which help in extracting capture groups etc. And hence the gap in my understanding.